# Unity 3D side by side screen resolution

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

I am creating a multiplayer game in Unity and as with a lot of multiplayer games I want the user to have a top down view of both his own game map and the other players game map. I want the world to be in 3D and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get both players to see the same things due to different screen resolutions. I obviously don't mind - and kind of expect - that I will need some black bordering.

The first screen resolution issue comes when rendering the view to a texture, and then the second screen resolution issue comes when rendering the texture to the UI. This is currently blowing my mind.

Is this possible with Unity and what would be the best approach? Am I barking up the wrong tree by using render to texture at all?

**EDIT:**

For clarity. Probably best described as a top down split screen, something like the following image, apart from it will be making use of full 3D and be at a slight angle.
[image]

Comment: So are you triying to make something like a mini map? I am confused. Could you provide images please ?

Comment: More like a top down split screen multiplayer - only using full 3D and with the camera at an angle. Illustration (from another game) has been added.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to keep the game "fair", so one player with higher resolution settings doesn't have an advantage over the other.

If that's the case, and you're happy with black borders, you can probably just use a mask in front of the camera.  As long as the mask is the same for both players, the resolution wouldn't make any difference other than quality.

Comment: Hi Ted, that's correct I'm trying to keep it fair. When you talk about a mask, what specifically do you mean? I've had a quick Google and found Camera.cullingMask but that appears to cull certain layers, I don't think that's what you mean?

Comment: A simple mask would just be a plane with a texture with a square hole in the middle, placed just in front of the camera.  You can tweak the distance and scales for best fit.  Another option is just putting 4 long skinny cubes into a square shape with the opening in the middle.